# How can we show that $\gamma+\ln x-H_{x-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cdots \,$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\gamma+\ln x -H_{x-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left({1\over xn}+{1\over xn+1}+{1\over xn+2}+\cdots+{1\over xn+x-1}-\ln{n+1\over n}\right)\tag1$$

$x\ge1$;integers

$H_{x}$ is the harmonic numbers

$H_0=0$

Setting $x=1$

We have Euler's constant

$$\gamma=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left({1\over n}-\ln{n+1\over n}\right)\tag2$$

How do we show that $(1)$?

An attempt we could substitute $(2)$ into $(1)$

Hence

$$\ln x - H_{x-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left({1\over xn}+{1\over xn+1}+{1\over xn+2} + \cdots+{1\over xn+x-1}-{1\over n}\right)\tag3$$

I don't know how to continue from here

Comment: What is the definition of $H_x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to finish your proof (assuming that $x$ is a positive integer):
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \left({1\over xn}+{1\over xn+1}+{1\over xn+2} + \cdots+{1\over xn+x-1}-{1\over n}\right)\\=\sum_{k=x}^{Nx+x-1}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}{1\over n}=H_{Nx+x-1}-H_{x-1}-H_N\\=\ln(Nx+x-1)-\ln(N)+o(1)-H_{x-1}\\=\ln(x+\frac{x-1}{N})+o(1)-H_{x-1}\to\ln(x)-H_{x-1}\quad \mbox{as $N\to+\infty$}$$
where I used the fact that $H_N=\ln(N)+\gamma +o(1)$.

Comment: I second Victor's comment on the original question: what's $H_x$? Or is $x$ restricted to be a nonnegative integer?